# VB only one If statement working in timer

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, timer

I've been looking around and I haven't seen anyone with this problem and I need some help with this. I'm working on an alarm screen with several buttons that will show the state each alarm is in by color. I constantly check the state using a timer that looks at an array of incoming data from a PLC. When I run the code, only the first button changes color, none of the others do anything. I'm not sure what I have to do. Here is a sample of what I'm doing

```
     Private Sub AlarmInformation_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Timer1.Interval = 2000
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'Alarm0
    If MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm0) = 0 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen
    ElseIf MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm0) = 2 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Red
    ElseIf MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm0) = 3 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    ElseIf MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm0) = 4 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Gray
    End If
    'Alarm1
    If MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm1) = 0 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen
    ElseIf MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm1) = 2 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Red
    ElseIf MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm1) = 3 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    ElseIf MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm1) = 4 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Gray
    End If
    'Alarm2
    If MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm2) = 0 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen
    ElseIf MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm2) = 2 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Red
    ElseIf MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm2) = 3 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    ElseIf MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm2) = 4 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Gray
    End If
    'Alarm3
    If MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm3) = 0 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen
    ElseIf MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm3) = 2 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Red
    ElseIf MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm3) = 3 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    ElseIf MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm3) = 4 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Gray
    End If
    'Alarm4
    If MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm4) = 0 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen
    ElseIf MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm4) = 2 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Red
    ElseIf MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm4) = 3 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    ElseIf MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm4) = 4 Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.Gray
    End If
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You only reference one button (`Button1`), so presumably that is the one that changes colour.

Comment: oh man I didn't catch that when I was coping my working code. That's probably the issue. I'll make a change and get back to you.

Comment: That was what the issue was. Thanks for the extra set of eyes.

Comment: May I suggest using a dictionary to associate the numbers and the colors? It will remove pretty much all of this code.

Comment: I've never used a dictionary before so it never crossed my mind. I'll look into dictionaries in vb. @Ares do you have any suggestions on how to use the library in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) for this purpose, to eliminate the extra `if` statements.

Here's some sample code that you could use:

```
    Dim openWith As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Color)

    ' Add some elements to the dictionary. There are no 
    ' duplicate keys, but some of the values are duplicates.
    openWith.Add(0, Color.ForestGray)
    openWith.Add(2, Color.Red)
    '... and so on.
    'Accessing the colors:
    openWith(MainForm.inputDataReals(MainForm.AOEnumArray.Alarm0))
```

That will spit out the color associated with the number.
Each block of 4 else/ifs gets reduced to a single line. You can even make dictionaries of arbitrary keys, so you could have Buttons and Alarms linked together.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip. The less complicated the code the better